# Layering image over royalslider in a vertical center position

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, slider

I'm attempting to layer a logo over the Royalslider plugin. It's set to 100% width and a flexible width to accommodate a responsive layout. I used css to position a logo on top of the Royalslider. It works but not totally how I'd like it. I basically calculate the current height of the slider and set the CSS margin-top to that value divided by 1.5.

I'm looking to have it vertically centered no matter what the size of the browser window. Is this possible? Does my math need tweaking? Any thoughts are appreciated.

Relevant URL:

http://www.bigideaadv.com/big_idea_v2/

Current HTML:

```
<div id="new-royalslider-1" class="royalSlider new-royalslider-1 rsUni rs-default-template" style="width:100%; height:450px;">
    <div class="rsContent">
        <img class="rsImg" src="http://www.bigideaadv.com/big_idea_v2/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/top_slide11-1024x560.jpg" alt="Entemanns slide"/>
    </div>
    <div class="rsContent">
        <img class="rsImg" src="http://www.bigideaadv.com/big_idea_v2/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/top_slide1-1024x560.jpg" alt="PGPF Slide"/>
    </div>
    <div class="rsContent">
        <img class="rsImg" src="http://www.bigideaadv.com/big_idea_v2/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/top_slide3-1024x560.jpg" alt="American Arbitration Association slide"/>
    </div>
    <div class="rsContent">
        <img class="rsImg" src="http://www.bigideaadv.com/big_idea_v2/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/top_slide4-1024x560.jpg" alt="GDLSK slide"/>
    </div>
    <div class="rsContent">
        <img class="rsImg" src="http://www.bigideaadv.com/big_idea_v2/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/top_slide5-1024x560.jpg" alt="uShuttl slide"/>
    </div>
</div>
<p id="floating-logo" class="align-center"><img src="wp-content/themes/skeleton/images/parallax_logo.png" /></p>
```

Current CSS (for p tag only):

```
#floating-logo {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3000;
}

#floating-logo img {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    offsetHeight = jQuery("#new-royalslider-1").height();
    offsetHeight = 0 - offsetHeight / 1.5;
    //console.log(offsetHeight);

    jQuery("p#floating-logo").css("margin-top", offsetHeight);
    //console.log(jQuery("p#floating-logo").css("margin-top"));

    $(window).resize(function() {
        offsetHeight = jQuery("#new-royalslider-1").height();
        offsetHeight = 0 - offsetHeight / 1.5;
        console.log(offsetHeight);

        jQuery("p#floating-logo").css("margin-top", offsetHeight);
        console.log(jQuery("p#floating-logo").css("margin-top"));
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CPU intensive jQuery resizing, just used media-query breakpoints, absolute and fixed position on the p and img elements respectively. top: 50% on p element and width on img set per breakpoint.